# SED bash remote replace text

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Hello I try using sed for change text:

```
 sshpass -e ssh $NAME@$IP "for i in `cat XXX/tabels.txt` ; do sed -e "s/'{\"keys\":\"ALL\", \"rows_per_partition\":\"NONE\"}'/{'keys':'ALL', 'rows_per_partition':'NONE'}/g" 
XXX/create/create_$i.txt > 
XXX/create/create_$i.new.txt && mv 
XXX/create/create_$i.new.txt 
XXX/create/create_$i.txt ; done"
```

I dont get some error but my changes are not saved.
Where is the problem ?

Comment: on side notes, you can just use "sed -i " for doing inplace replacement. no need to create a temp file.

Comment: ok, so I try using: 
sshpass -e ssh $NAME@$IP  "for i in \`cat XXX/tabels.txt\` ; do sed -i "s/'{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'/{'keys':'ALL', 'rows_per_partition':'NONE'}" XXX/create/create_$i.txt ; done"

but still I have this problem

Comment: @dzyzas probably not matching, download the file(s) and try it locally.

Comment: You should fix your nested quotes (you use quotes on your for statement, and then again in the sed expression within that for statement)